# How to fill my binary with 0s to the left in C Programming?

Tags: c, binary

Do you guys know how to fill my binary with 0s to the left? My function is:

```
void PrintBinaryUpTo(int n)
{
    int i;
    char string [11];
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        itoa(i, string, 2);

        printf("%d in binary is: %s\n", i, string);
    }
}
```

It returns this:

```
1 in binary is: 1
2 in binary is: 10
3 in binary is: 11
```

But I would like it to be like this:

```
1 in binary is: 0000000001
2 in binary is: 0000000010
3 in binary is: 0000000011
```

EDIT: I made it like this, but I'm pretty sure there are smarter ways to do it.

```
void PrintBinaryUpTo(int n)
{
    int i;
    char string [11];
    char result[11];
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        itoa(i, string, 2);

        switch(strlen(string))
        {
            case 1:
            strcpy(result, "000000000");
            strcat(result, string);
            break;

            case 2:
            strcpy(result, "00000000");
            strcat(result, string);
            break;

            case 3:
            strcpy(result, "0000000");
            strcat(result, string);
            break;

            case 4:
            strcpy(result, "000000");
            strcat(result, string);
            break;

            case 5:
            strcpy(result, "00000");
            strcat(result, string);
            break;

            case 6:
            strcpy(result, "0000");
            strcat(result, string);
            break;

            case 7:
            strcpy(result, "000");
            strcat(result, string);
            break;

            case 8:
            strcpy(result, "00");
            strcat(result, string);
            break;

            case 9:
            strcpy(result, "0");
            strcat(result, string);
            break;

            default:
            strcpy(result, string);
            break;
        }
        printf("%d in binary is: %s\n", i, result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 in binary is: 0000000001
2 in binary is: 0000000010
3 in binary is: 0000000011
4 in binary is: 0000000100
5 in binary is: 0000000101
6 in binary is: 0000000110
7 in binary is: 0000000111
8 in binary is: 0000001000
9 in binary is: 0000001001
```

Comment: The 'itoa' is C++

Comment: @dash-o I think the user defined their own `itoa`.

Comment: @dash-o, it's also "a widespread non-standard extension to the standard C programming language."

Comment: *"0s to the right?"* - or in this case to the *left* (ie. the "other" right).

Comment: `strcat(result, string);` is asking for trouble when the destination is no longer than the source.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not really any way to do this unless you define your own `itoa` function.
However, there *is* a portable way to simplify your function:

```
void PrintBinaryUpTo(int n)
{
    int i;
    char string[11];
    char result[11];
    char *zeroes = "000000000";
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        itoa(i, string, 2);
        /* Buffer the number to 10 digits */
        strcpy(result, zeroes+strlen(string)-1);
        strcat(result, string);
        printf("%d in binary is: %s\n", i, result);
    }
}
```

This doesn't require the whole `switch` `case` thing that you have.

An alternative that's not portable (it requires MSVC) is to use the `%010s` format specifier, which pads with zeroes:

```
void PrintBinaryUpTo(int n)
{
    int i;
    char string[11];
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        itoa(i, string, 2);
        /* Buffer the number to 10 digits with %010s */
        printf("%d in binary is: %010s\n", i, string);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to Clang 11.0.0, in the `printf` format string, combining the flag `0` with the conversion specifier `s` is undefined behavior in both C11 and C17. The resulting executable appears to zero-pad, at least in the very small number of test runs I've performed.

Comment: Instead of `strcpy` and `strcat` you could do  `printf("%d in binary is: %s%s\n", i, zeroes+strlen(string)-1, string);`

Comment: Yeah, I get that there's multiple solutions to this. I've chosen the most suggested fix and the solution closest to the OP's.